# Errors with Append tool 000594

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, feature-class, append, environment-variable

I am trying to No_Test append a polygon feature class to another polygon feature class. Both fc's are located in the same geodatabase. I am using the Append tool with ArcGIS 10.2.

I'm getting two errors, but to focus the question on one--I keep getting Error 000594: Input Feature 1L falls outside of output geometry domains.

I recall having this issue before and being able to fix it with environmental settings, but the error still occurs with the following set:

> Output Coordinates: Same as input
>
> Processing Extent: Union of inputs
>
> M and Z values have  been disabled (although there are no M or Z values for either fc. I've read that if the fc was created in ArcGIS 9.x or earlier, it may have issues with M or Z values.)
>
> Geodatabase Advanced: Maintain Spacial Index has been checked. Output M and Z are same as input.

Any suggestions on what else I should be troubleshooting?

Comment: Very common unfortunately when working with fgdb. When possible I export destination to shapefile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature classes that are created by importing from other formats can sometimes have limited XY domains, which can be very hard to rectify.  Creating a new feature class with default XY domain should resolve the issue.

Create a new (empty) feature class using your destination feature class as the template.  Then append your two original feature classes into the new feature class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change out the destination feature class. I have permissions to write to it and modify it, but am not high up enough on the hierarchy to make a bigger change like that (even if the resulting FC is exactly the same, I know someone would have issue with it..).

Comment: @JackOfTales, you'll need to talk with your system administrator in that case.  See also https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008530 ... "The extent of a geodatabase feature dataset or feature class can only be set when it is created. After the feature dataset or feature class is created, the extent cannot be changed."